# Allowing all hosts on map in Mapfish Print 2.1.2?

Tags: mapfish, mapfish-print, mapfish-print-2

My web mapping application has an option to load layers from any Geoserver layers. However, as far as I know so far mapfish requires hosts to be written in the config.yaml to be white-listed. This means printing will not work for layers added by a user from another server.

```
hosts: [*]
```

Is it possible to have a wildcard to allow all hosts or at least enable to set a variable so that hosts are white-listed dynamically?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: No, I didn't find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
- !ipMatch
host: 127.0.0.1
# Allow to all hosts
mask: 0.0.0.0
```